# SSH Kerberos Auth in Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: ssh, mac, kerberos, lion

I just upgrade my Mac OS to 10.7 Lion.

It has worked well before. But , Only kinit working normally now, can't ssh to my server.

After reinstall the "Mac OS X Kerberos Extras" , nothing better.

Anyone give me a help? Thanks a lot!!

my command line :

```
Myname$ ssh root@10.3.18.211 -v

......

debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
UNKNOWN_SERVER while looking up 'host/10.3.18.211@3.18.211' (cached result, timeout in 1200 sec)

debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@10.3.18.211's password:
```

Comment: Just Follow this link : http://superuser.com/questions/315164/cant-connect-to-my-server-using-ssh-kerberos-auth-on-osx-10-7/315192#315192

Answer (score 1):

You need to SSH to your server's FQDN and not its IP address. Make sure the server's principal name is the FQDN.

Comment: or you can disable strict checking and add IPs to your kerberos as well (but that's ugly)